# Cannot deserialize a 'String' from BsonType 'Boolean'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

i am getting error in a "isActive filed" and in a catch error message says that

> "An error occurred while deserializing the isActive property of class TimeClock.Model.UserModel: Cannot deserialize a 'String' from BsonType 'Boolean'."

```
List<UserModel> lstemployee = new List<UserModel>();    
UserModel employee = new UserModel();
try
{
    Connection cn = new Connection();
    IMongoDatabase server = cn.ConnectionString();
    var collection = server.GetCollection<UserModel>("users");
    //  ObjectId id = ObjectId.Parse(ObjParam._id);
    var email = ObjParam.email_id;
    var builder = Builders<UserModel>.Filter;
    var filter = builder.Eq( "email_id", email);

    var obj = collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
    if (obj != null && obj.Result != null)
    {
        lstemployee = obj.Result.Select(x => new UserModel()
        {
            _id = Convert.ToString(x._id),
            user_id = x.user_id,
            role_id = x.role_id,
            first_name = x.first_name,
            last_name = x.last_name,
            email_id = x.email_id,
            user_name = x.user_name,
            password = x.password,
            gender = x.gender,
            birth_date = x.birth_date,
            cell_phone = x.cell_phone,
            address = x.address,
            access_level = x.access_level,
            security_question = x.security_question,
            security_answer = x.security_answer,
            business_id = x.business_id,
            created_by = x.created_by,
            created_date = x.created_date,
            modified_by = x.modified_by,
            modified_date = x.modified_date,
            isActive = x.isActive.ToString()
        }).ToList();
```

and following is my `usermodel` class

```
public string email_id { get; set; }
public string created_by { get; set; }
public string created_date { get; set; }
public string modified_by { get; set; }
public string modified_date { get; set; }
public string isActive { get; set; }
```

Comment: Error looks pretty clear. In database it's boolean, but in your model `isActive` is for some reason a string.

Comment: no i checked my database it is string not boolean

Comment: What happens when you remove `.ToString()`?

Comment: its give me a same error

Comment: Have you analyzed all result documents or just one? I think @Evk is probably very correct in his first comment...

Comment: yes i checked all the document and all have string value